# Is an unconditional basic income pleasurable idea or it cannot be achieved?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, welfare-economics, basic-income

I would like to know if you can tell me, what are economical theories that are in support of this kind of social system if any? Can this system be efficient?

Comment: This is off-topic here on Skeptics, but might be well-received on [Politics.se] or [Economics.se].

Comment: Check out this paper: https://public.econ.duke.edu/~erw/197/forget-cea%20(2).pdf

Comment: Freakonomics (or was it NPR Money podcast?) recently ran an issue on the topic, referencing some research